# Android: PhoneStateListener not updated during long send/receive data operation

Tags: android, updates, phone-state-listener

I have wrote an app using the PhoneStateListener to get updates for level (signal strength), cell location etc. Normally this works fine and I have no problems. I see level updates normally every 1 or 2 seconds.

In the same app I can start a file download and after this an upload. The file is 2MB - but I have a timeout so that I cancel the down-/upload after 10 seconds. All of this I do in an extra thread and this works also fine.

But: During the download/upload no update of the level occur. Normally this could be a problem in my code - yes.

But I can reproduce it: If I am driving with train I surfed a news page (www.spiegel.de) with lots of text and images. And as I have seen, that the download hangs somewhere in the middle I opened the telephone info. And the update of the level hangs too! The level is update nearly 5-10s the download was finished.

This problem occur on different phones with different OS (samsung, htc, android 2.3.3-4.0.x).

So this seems to be a system problem and it may be, this is not the right group.

But I hope somebody can help or knows about this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Axel